# What is the loader setting relative to?

Tags: webpack

I am working with a project with a working webpack config. I want to reorganize the file structure. I'm trying to figure out how the existing config refers to the files. Here is the line from my config which confuses me:

```
loader: "style!css!sass?outputStyle=expanded&includePaths[]=&" +
        (path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules"))
```

The node_modules directory in my project is two levels up from where the config file is ("../../node_modules"). Also, we run the `webpack` command from the same directory as the config file.

How does webpack know it should go two levels up to find the node_modules directory?

Comment: (also, i'm a webpack newb, so i welcome suggestions to improving the wording of this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Node's module system is implemented: when it can't find a `node_modules` in the current directory, it will go up one directory level (`../`) and check there, etc.

That behaviour is also explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

FWIW, the loader configuration you're showing seems to set `includePaths` wrong: the `&` at the end of the string should not be there. Also, since it seems to be adding a non-existent `node_modules` to the include path, I think you can shorten it to this:

```
loader: "style!css!sass?outputStyle=expanded"
```